# fprintf has problems with characters returned by a function

Tags: c++, char, printf

I have two problems. Both can be illustrated by this simple code (compiled with g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++14):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const char *printi(const unsigned long &i) {
    return to_string(i)).c_str();
}

int main() {    
    unsigned long i1 = 1; unsigned long i2 = 2;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", printi(i1), printi(i2));
}
```

Problem no. 1 - It prints "11", while it should print "12".

Problem no. 2 - Sometimes it doesn't print numbers at all, but some weird characters instead.

Comment: Interestingly when I run this code I get 22 as my output. Why are you printing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: You're returning a temporary = bad news.

Comment: How can I work if I can't use the values my function returns? :( I need to put that string into fprintf...

(the whole code is just an abstraction of something much bigger, and this is supposed to be a debug information, that's why it is stderr)

Comment: @Jecke: Are you writing C or C++? Use a `std::string`, use `std::cerr` if you're writing C++

Comment: I'm writing in C++, but I use fprintf because it's much more convenient.
I can have `fprintf("blah %s blah %lu blah %s\n", a, b, c)` instead of `cerr << "blah" << a << "blah" << b << "blah" << c << endl;`... it's much shorter and flexible. In fact, I have `#define debug_out( ... ) if (debug) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__ )` at the beginning and I don't have to worry about how much different arguments I want to print and it's much much cleaner

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. Answers go in the Answer box. You can either accept someone's answer, or post and accept your own answer.

Comment: BTW in C++ you can rig up something like `tprint("blah % blah % blah", a, b, c);` where you don't need a format specifier because it detects the format from the type of the argument

Comment: ok, sorry. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that `std::to_string()` returns a `std::string`.  This `std::string` exists only inside of the `printi()` function scope, which means when you exit the function (when you `return`), the destructor of this `std::string` is called, and the address you return (the value returned by `c_str()`) no longer points to valid memory.  Your code has undefined behavior, because you don't know to which data it is now pointing.

In order to fix this, you can have `printi()` return a `std::string` instead, which will be deep copied into the caller upon `return`, and then the caller can use `c_str()` as needed:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string printi(const unsigned long &i) {
    return to_string(i);
}

int main() {    
    unsigned long i1 = 1; unsigned long i2 = 2;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", printi(i1).c_str(), printi(i2).c_str());
}
```

Comment: True. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... so if I create a function int return5() { short a = 5; return a; }, I cannot expect that cout << 2*return5(); will print 10? Or does this only not work with strings?

Comment: *"In order to fix it you can return a reference to std::string"* -- It sounds like you're suggesting replacing a dangling pointer with a dangling reference. If not, I'm not sure what you're suggesting here.

Comment: Well this will actually work, when you return an object (char*, int) then it is just copied, for int it will copy its data, for char* it will copy its address. If you return std::string it will copy its data as well But when you exit the scope, the destructor is called, and now the address of the c_str string, is not valid anymore, the memory was cleaned! Now you hold in your hands non valid address and you try to print it.

Comment: @Jecke: A better analogy would be if you created a function like this: `int* return5() { int a = 5; return &a; }` -- In which case you have no guarantee that `cout << *return5();` will print 5.

Comment: I see, thanks :) I changed the return type to string and now I have fprintf(...printi(i1).c_str()...) and it works!